# Upwards Transverse in Javascript DOM

Tags: javascript, html, dom

I want to transverse upwards in javascript. like if i give input an element it will show all its parent elements till html tag but its not working like that. It only shows `DIV,BODY,HTML`.

```js
function Transverse(p) {
  var path = "";
  var A = [];
  var element = document.querySelector(document.getElementById(p).nodeName);
  path = element.parentElement;
  while (path) {
    A.push(path);
    path = path.parentElement;
  }
  console.log(A);

}
```

```html
<div>
  <button id="btn1" onclick="Transverse('btn1')">button 1</button>
  <ul>
    <button id="btn2" onclick="Transverse('btn2')">button 2</button>
    <li>
      <button id="btn3" onclick="Transverse('btn3')">button 3</button>
    </li><br>

    <section>
      <a href="#">
        <button id="btn4" onclick="Transverse('btn4')">button 4</button>

      </a>
    </section>
  </ul>
  <ol>
    <li>
      <h1>End of Page</h1>
      <button id="btn5" onclick="Transverse('btn5')">Button 5</button>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Comment: How about `var element = document.getElementById(p);`?

Comment: Says who? Using my suggestion fixes the code. `nodeName` is `"BUTTON"`, which means you lose the information *which* button's id was passed to the function.

Comment: @saifkhan with the condition from your last comment following happens, whatever button element gets queried first by id, its nodeName will always be `button` which then is the query string for `document.querySelector`  which returns always the first button element of your document structure; its chain of parent is most probably very short and always the same result, regardless of what an `id` was provided at first place.

Comment: Thanks all it works now !. I did the following Changes                                      function Transverse(p){
            var A=[];
            var element = document.getElementById(p);
            var path=element.parentElement;
            while(path){
                A.push(path.nodeName);
                path=path.parentElement;
            }
            console.log(A);
            
        }

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all it is working now ! I did the following Changes

```
function Transverse(p){ 
var A=[]; 
var element = document.getElementById(p); 
var path=element.parentElement; 
while(path){ 
A.push(path.nodeName); 
path=path.parentElement; 
} 
console.log(A); 
}
```